# How to convert a string containing a hex character code to the character value?

Tags: c

I have an array of chars `"0x55"`.
What I want to do is convert it to a `char` which is going to be `U` (because ASCII 0x55 = `U`).

So how to do this conversion?

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
array[] = "0x55"
char test;

**// I want to move the string to that test to be one character which is U**

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Maybe if you include an example of the output that should appear?

Comment: The question is just about as understandable as your name.

Comment: Is your question c or c++? It does make a difference.

Comment: in c grizzly & mark-ransom cool you are da man__

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Good questions on SO are clearly explained and show some evidence of effort.  Unfortunately, this question does not show signs of effort.  The fragment of code won't compile (you've omitted a type before the name `array`, presumably `char`).

Comment: "Any suggestions?" : I'd write some code for that. Perhaps you can do the same.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are after:

```
int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
  char array[] = "0x55";
  int value;
  char test;

  sscanf(array,"%x",&value);
  test = value;

  return 0;
}
```

In C++, I would code it a little differently, but this seems more like a C question.

Comment: closed as not a real question by it seems some people they do not know how to answer it then a closing it is much better!@@

Comment: No, it's not a real question, because the whole question assumes that one knows that 0x55 is the letter U, and further you are not really supposed to have your homework done by other peopple.

Comment: in c++ : http://ideone.com/3KjmF1

Comment: @MsdsdWrqw, I'm genuinely amazed that anyone was able to decipher what you were looking for.